# como llamar a una funcion luego de 60 minutos con redux-saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

**Mi codigo**

```
function* startCountTimeForMove(time: number) {
  yield delay(time);
  yield alertTime('Lo sentimos', 'Se agotó el tiempo,  ¿aún quieres completar la encuesta?');

}
```

Comment: Hay un inconveniente, y si el usuario recarga la pagina?, te haz puesto a pensar en ello?, si no hay inconvenientes con que se resetee el tiempo al recargar la pagina entonces no necesitarias un generador, una funcion comun y corriente seria mas ligera, aunque si deseas mantener el tiempo para cuando se recargue la pagina si que habra inconvenientes, aunque igual te recomiendo leer sobre las funciones `setInterval` y `setTimeout`, te ayudaran en ese proposito, pero idealmente te diria que no uses un un `setInterva`l o un `setTimeout` con un generador para ese proposito.

Comment: En su lugar una funcion normal.